# How to randomly choose child gameobjects in clumps

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a simple village building game in Unity3D, C#. I made it so the game would generate a 50x50 block of ground that are clones of a prefab. How would I make it so clumps of grass (each seperate gameobjects) would be classified as a forest through script (by giving it a different tag)?

Current script:

```
//GameObjects
public GameObject cube;
public GameObject groundParent;

//Integers
public int worldWidthX;
public int worldWidthZ;
public int mapHeight;

//Floats
private float mapSizeX;
private float mapSizeZ;

public void GenerateTerrain()
{
    for(int x = 0; x <= this.worldWidthX; x++, x++)
    {
        for(int z = 0; z <= this.worldWidthZ; z++, z++)
        {
            float y = /*Mathf.PerlinNoise(x / 30, 76) * Mathf.PerlinNoise(z / 30, 22) * 40;*/ mapHeight;
            GameObject groundChild = Instantiate(this.cube, new Vector3(x, y, z), this.cube.transform.rotation);
            groundChild.transform.parent = groundParent.transform;
        }
    }

    forestMaxAmount = (worldWidthX * worldWidthZ) / 8;
    forestMinAmount = (worldWidthX * worldWidthZ) / 25;

    forestAmount = Mathf.RoundToInt(Random.Range (forestMinAmount, forestMaxAmount));
    Debug.Log (forestAmount);
}
```

Hierarchy:
http://prntscr.com/htx5gc

If there is any way in which I can make this question more specific/understandable, I'd be glad to do so. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Noting in your code made an attempt to generate a random number. Just Google how to generate random number in Unity.

Comment: I understand your point, I was just wondering how I would be able to randomly select this random amount of child gameobjects and then apply different tags to them.

Comment: It is possible. Edit your question and show that you can generate random number in Unity. If you can't do that, Google it. Once you find how to do that attempt to do what you have in this question. Again, ifyou can't, post that code.

Comment: Using this code, I would imagine making a for loop to run until the random amount of gameobjects have been chosen. I just have no idea how I would go about randomly choosing these gameobjects.

Comment: I see your edit. What are you trying to randomize? Read your question but still don't understand your goal here.

Comment: My goal is to choose a random number of gameobjects (which i got with the edit) from all of those children displayed within the hierarchy. All I have left to figure out is how to find out which child gameobjects I would randomly choose with that number.

Comment: The `groundChild` in your code refers to an instantiated object with many child objects and you want to pick one from that child object?

Comment: The *groundChild* in my code refers to an object that is being instantiated inside of the *parentGround* object. The *groundChild* object is all of those child objects. It's just a name made so that it is instantiated inside of the *parentGround* object.
prntscr.com/hty0o7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A community member on the Unity answers website provided this solution to my issue. It comes up with a random child index number from the selection available, then gets that child, adding it to a list. It also makes sure repeated selections aren't repeated again.

```
HashSet<int> alreadyChosen = new HashSet<int>();

    for (var i = 0; i <= forestAmount; i++) 
    {
        int randomChildIdx = Random.Range(0, groundParent.transform.childCount);
        while (alreadyChosen.Contains(randomChildIdx))
            randomChildIdx = Random.Range(0, groundParent.transform.childCount);

        alreadyChosen.Add(randomChildIdx);
        Transform randomChild = groundParent.transform.GetChild(randomChildIdx);
        // randomChild is now a random child of groundParent. Do whatever you need to with it.
        forestObjects.Add(randomChild);
        randomChild.tag = "Forest";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need one tag for each clump, then

```
groundChild.tag = "Forest";
// and search for them later on
GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Forest");
```

Assuming that you've made a "Forest" tag in your inspector. More info [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Tags.html).

That said, it may be faster and more clear to either have a TerrainManager object which contains a list of all things you deem as terrain, and stores them internally in an array. In this way you could have quicker access, or fancier access (give me the clump at row 5, column 3, if available).  Making my city-builder for a jam, I ended up going this route for buildings as it was definitely easier to work with.

Comment: Thank you, this answer is very helpful. All I have left to figure out is how to find out which child gameobjects I would randomly choose.